# Apple App Store Connect: Simple dummy-proof environment protection

Tags: ios, environment-variables, app-store, release-management, app-store-connect

We have an iOS app which connects to a cloud server. During development we use environment parameters that point to the development or staging cloud. But for the release we must point to the production cloud server.

Is there any way to prevent an app with development or staging environment parameters from being released with App Store Connect?

As far as I know it is not possible to:

- Upload a snapshot version (e.g. 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT), apple enforces [number].[number].[number].
- Upload a lower version: e.g. 0.0.0 to ensure it is a work in progress.
- Name uploaded builds or see the archive name (they just have a build number and a version).
- Tag a build with for e.g. [STAGING], once uploaded.

For android we fix this by using Jenkins jobs to release the app, but with apple this is not possible because there is no way to determine the correct build, there is no way to release automated and there is that terrible review process.

I find it extremely hard to believe that there is a release tool not providing such basic features, so I'm clearly missing something. What is the correct way to realize this with App Store Connect?

**Update**:

Added picture to clarify what I mean:
[image]

How do I know which of these builds point to which environment? How can I enforce that only the production environment builds will ever be submitted for review?

Comment: "but with apple this is not possible because there is no way to determine the correct build, there is no way to release automated and there is that terrible review process." how do you mean? I've used Jenkins and other tools such as fastlane for years with iOS. We have around 7 build configurations for various things, each build can change things like API URL's, debug options, logging levels, turns features on/off etc. Just test your build configurations to ensure the options are being applied as expected

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your comment. We do use Jenkins to build, increase version and upload, but how can you configure Jenkins to ensure a staging or develop build will never be submitted for review? I've updated the post with an image to clarify my issue

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your issue here. In my jenkins instance, i have a job for each type of build that I can do. For test, non-live, ad-hoc etc the build job creates the build and uploads the enterprise app to our own storage for internal distribution. The only job that has an upload to store step is the release job. So none of our staging, test, debug builds etc could reach the store.

Comment: and yes, your right, you can't add anything within the built product to determine what   configuration was used to build it as far as I know, thats why we split our jenkins jobs and only allow jenkins to upload the build to store, if it is a release job

Comment: We push the staging build to Test-Flight, so all our colleagues can test it during two weeks or something. The new features are only available on the staging environment and we try to release the app and server with only 1 day in between

Comment: Do you know of a good way to test company wide, without Test-Flight? Manually installing is a lot of hassle + no auto feedback from crashes

Comment: My company uses an enterprise licence so we can just install the build on our devices manually by dragging the ipa to the device in the devices window. We aren't really supposed to be putting builds on testflight that wont go live. I used to use Fabric beta for this, but its been replaced now with https://firebase.google.com/products/app-distribution